# Misplaced \noalign while using parbox and alignment options

Tags: tables

I have setup my table shape as follow:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright} p{1.7cm}>{\raggedleft}
p{1.5cm}>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}>{\raggedleft} p{1.6cm} >{\raggedleft}
p{2cm}}
```

But when I try to compile it I see `Misplaced \noalign` error for some of rows in the table. 
If I delete `\raggedleft` for the last column the error does not appear.
I really have no ideas.

Answer (score 2):

`\raggedleft` redefines `\\` so losing its "end of table row" meaning, either use

```
\raggedleft\arraybackslash
```

so `\\` is restored, or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` to end the table row.

Comment: Thank you so much!